# Http Request inside forEach - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, asynchronous, npm

I have spreadsheets with data that needs to be uploaded via an API. After extracting the data from the spreadsheet, I create an object and put it in an array.

My idea was to iterate over this array and make a request for every single object in there and use the status code to display a success or error message.
  The code seems to work fine with small quantities (~ 200 elements) but when I try to stress it (lets say 3500 elements), the line `response.statusCode` breaks because `response` is undefined. I thought I wouldn't have any problems with the async part because the callback would be called only when the server responded, but it seems not to be the case here.
Why am I getting `response` undefined in a callback?

Here's a piece of code i'm using:

```
array.forEach(function (element) {
        //Configure Request
        var options = {
            url: 'http://example',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            body: element,
            json: true
        }

        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(response.statusCode);
                console.log(body)
            } else {
                console.log(response.statusCode);
                console.log(error)

            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should go with `async.each()` of `async` library  https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html

Comment: Are you intending on firing 3500 requests at once because that's what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

Please run this code in async.mapLimit()

https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapLimit